# If $\operatorname{Im}(x) \perp \operatorname{Im}(y)$, then $\|x+y\| = \max\{\|x\|, \|y\|\}$.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $x,y \in B(H)$ be bounded operators on the Hilbert space $H$ such that
$xy=yx = 0$ and $\operatorname{Im}(x) \perp \operatorname{Im}(y)$. Moreover, assume that
$\operatorname{Im}(y)$ has finite-dimension. Then is it true that
$$\|x+y\| = \max\{\|x\|, \|y\|\}?$$

I tried to mimique the proof of Pythagoras theorem but did not manage to prove this result. I'm not even sure it is true, but it looks like a result that is used in a proof I'm reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit: ruy noted that the original example didn't work.**

This is not true, even if $\dim H<\infty$. For instance consider
$$
x=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\ 1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix},\qquad y=\begin{bmatrix} 0&0&0\\0&0&0\\1&0&0\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
Then $xy=yx=0$, ranges are orthogonal, and
$$
\|x\|=\|y\|=1,\qquad\|x+y\|=\sqrt2.
$$
The equality does hold when $x$ and $y$ are also selfadjoint. Or, more generally, when $x^*y=yx^*=0$. Because in this case one has
$$\|x+y\|^2=\|(x+y)^*(x+y)\|=\|x^*x+y^*y\|=\max\{\|x\|^2,\|y\|^2\}$$ by the selfadjoint case.

Comment: What if $x,y$ are unitaries?

Comment: Them you cannot have neither $xy=0$ nor orthogonal images.

Comment: I guess $yx\neq0$.

Comment: You are right. Edited.

Comment: I guess the equality also holds when, in addition,  $x^*y=yx^*=0$.

Comment: Yes, in that situation you have $$\|x+y\|^2=\|(x+y)^*(x+y)\|=\|x^*x+y^*y\|=\max\{\|x\|^2,\|y\|^2\}$$ by the selfadjoint case.

Comment: Nice.  And all you need is that $x^*y=yx^*=0$.